# Alguém poderia explicar este código em batch para mim?

Tags: cmd, batch

Alguém poderia explicar este código para mim?

Eu sei noção do que se trata, mas não consigo aplica-lo.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%A in ('wmic baseboard get serialnumber /value ^| find /i "SerialNumber="') do set serialnumber=%%A
if /i not "%serialnumber%" == "PF0TPMUN" goto :exit
```

Answer (score 1):

O `for /f` é um comando para uso em loopings, aonde vai permitir obter e manipular as informações que retornarem de sua execução, quer seja invocando um programa, um comando interno/externo do sistema, um outro for looping, um outro script, enfim, um ou mais comandos, e as suas respectivas saídas serão submetidos para os tratamentos que o autor do código desenvolveu, e que vai resumir em ações que resultem em algo proveitoso para ele de alguma forma.

For /f também pode ser usado para processar o conteúdo de arquivos (legível, imprimível, entenda "texto"), e o conforme o objetivo do usuário, o `for /f` vai abrir, ler, escrever, e desenvolver as ações com os dados do(s) do(s) arquivo(s) e/ou com as saídas dos comandos que forem passados dentro das ações do loop, quer numa prévia ação de filtragem no conteúdo da saída, ou nas manipulações que retornarem dessa execução, usando opções como o uso de aspas com `usebackq`, pulando uma ou mais linhas na saída, com `skip`, definir o qual/quais pegar com `tokens`, e quer na/no a1ª token, e/ou o2ª, e/ou o 3ª, e/ou todas (*) as ocorrências restantes, além de também definir ou/não, um delimitador apropriado (ou múltiplos, se for o caso) com `delims`, e também qual caractere vais usar para definir/limitar o final de linha, com `eol`.

Mas agora que tens uma breve noção do que envolve um comando `for /f`, você pode tentar ver nesse seu comando `for /f`, que vai executar o`wmic.exe` já passando alguns argumentos para que obtenha/retorne o número serial da placa mãe do computador, além já ter definido que dessa saída, ele vai usar apenas o texto/strings que vem no segundo `token`, assumindo como delimitadores (múltiplos), o sinal de igual e o espaço.

Observe que nessa execução, as strings resultantes desse comando `wmic + for`, e, na verdade, eles estão fazendo uma pré-seleção/(filtragem) direto da saída da execução, e manipulando as strings conforme definido nos argumentos do `wmic /value` com as opções do `for /f tokens=2 delims== "`, para depois enviar/direcionar o que sobrar para uso dentro do loop pelos comandos seguintes, como o `set`, que vei definir uma variável armazenado as strings presentes no serial da placa, e o `if` que vai testar uma condição e comparar o que retornou com uma string "PF0TPMUN", se a condição se mostrar verdadeira na comparação de igualdade da string "conhecida", o bat segue as ações imediatamente posteriores a esse loop, mas se não forem iguais, vai para o label `:exit` e executa os comandos que está tens "enfileirado".

Sobre uso de multiplicidade no delimitador, isso é dispensável para obtenção do serial, entendendo que a execução `wmic` não vai precisar do argumento `/value`, que acabam obrigando o uso das opções do `for`, mas, em fazendo a remoção desse argumento, você também pode remover os do `for /f "tokens=2 delims== "`, e usar apenas o `skip^=1` no seu `for`, que vai pular a primeira linha na saída, e com a ausência de um tokens/delims definidos, o `"tokens=1 delims= "` por padrão serão usados.

Observe o `wmic` sem `/value`, e o `for /f` apenas usando `skip^=1`:

- E veja a saída com linha adicional por conta do unicode do output do `wmic`, e é visível na primeira execução, mas **removida** na segunda com substituição do `find "SerialNumber=" pelo simples uso do **`findstr .`** // siga o` ^< nul` no primeiro comando, e perca ele de vista na segunda execução:

**[Sobre a linha adicional por conta do unicode no  output do `wmic`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3270)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Obs.: 1** No caso de rodar em um computador netbook/laptop/desktop de marca/fabricado, é comum o número serial da placa mãe ser o mesmo do serial da bios.

**Obs.: 2** Eu usaria `wmic bios get serialnumber` direto, depois passaria para uma conversão dessa num hash, e essa string em md5, ou shada vida, é o que eu usária para comparação, ai sim, a edição do código não deixaria "facilitado" para alteração manipulação de "validador, e isso usando o `certUtil.exe` que já vem com o Windows.

---

```bat
    O comando wmic baseboard get serialnumber /value
    Saida do comando: SerialNumber=PE03A187      -> = // Meu Computador
    Delimitadores 2 : "delims== " =igual+espaço  -> = // Delims==' ' 
    Saida com for /F: tokens 1    =tokens 2      -> = // Tokens=2 
                      ignorado    =ocorrência    -> = // PE03A187
```

**Obs.: 3**  Não existe um segundo sinal de igual, o que vem após primeiro
também é o segundo token!

- Para obter ajuda e onde encontar os comandos utilizados:

```bat
     if | Comando: Interno do cmd.exe
        | Caminho: C:\WINDOWS\System32\CMD.exe
        |   Ajuda: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k if /?
        
    set | Comando: Interno do cmd.exe 
        | Caminho: C:\WINDOWS\System32\CMD.exe
        |   Ajuda: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k set /? 

    for | Comando: Interno do cmd.exe
        | Caminho: C:\WINDOWS\System32\CMD.exe
        |   Ajuda: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k for /? 
            
   find | Comando: Interno do cmd.exe
        | Caminho: C:\WINDOWS\System32\CMD.exe
        |   Ajuda: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k find /?
            
   goto | Comando: Interno do cmd.exe 
  ref.: | Caminho: C:\WINDOWS\System32\CMD.exe
  :exit |   Ajuda: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k goto /?
            
   wmic | Comando: Externo do Windows
        | Caminho: C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
        |   Ajuda: C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /? 

findstr | Comando: Externo do Windows
        | Caminho: C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe
        |   Ajuda: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k findstr /?

        rem :: Os comandos listados aqui funcionam para linda de comando e
               também no iniciar / executar do Windows, case quera copiar
               as saídas para ler de outra forma(editor de text) adicione
               | clip e cole onde desejar: 
                 Ex.:   for /? | clip
```

- Uma sugestão de edição/alteração no código para o seu bat:

O `^< nul set^` é um escape para toda linha, onde a saída sera tratada como texto escapando qualquer caractere não alfanumérico que possa vir de uma placa estilo "ching ling", e com o `findstr .` para encontrar qualquer caractere, ajudando a lidar com a linha que juto do unicode que vem trazendo um adicional  no final da string. Já o `skip^=1` é para pular/ignorar a primeira linha na saída do `wmic`, e um outra coisa, no seu comando `set`, procura usar aspas `set AbreAspasVariavel=ValorFecheAspas` == `set "SerialNumber=PE03A187"`

```
for /f skip^=1 %%i in ('^<con: wmic.exe baseboard get serialnumber^|findstr .
')do ^< nul set^ "SerialNumber=%%~i" & if not "%%~A" == "PF0TPMUN" goto=:exit
```

---