# Pra quê serve e como usar essa expressão?

Tags: windows, batch, terminal

Eu gostaria de copiar os arquivos mais recentes, de um diretório para outro. Além de ser o `mais recente (por data de criação)` tenho outras condições para a cópia:

- Começar com `"Relatório Financeiro"`
- Copiar arquivos de extensão `.PDF` ou `.XLSX`.

Pesquisando sobre o assunto dei de cara com esta expressão na comunidade Super User, porém sendo iniciante não possuía pontuação suficiente para comentar e pedir mais esclarecimentos sobre o trecho de código.

```
@Echo off
Set "Xnewest=2"
For /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'Dir /B /A-D /O-D ^| Findstr /N "^"'
) Do If %%A Leq %Xnewest% echo Move "%%B" "X:\Path\to\dest\"
```

Já dei uma pesquisada e tenho uma noção básica mas gostaria de saber se alguém saberia esclarecer ***o que*** essa expressão faz e ***como*** ela faz.

Qualquer alternativa pro meu problema será igualmente bem vinda.

Comment: Se a ideia eh mover **apenas** 1 par de arquivos (1 .pdf + 1 .xlsx) por execução, daí a sugestão seria outra.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe li a sua reposta e você matou todas as minhas dúvidas com relação a expressão, agradeço demais cara! Eu realmente não inseri na pergunta mas gostaria de copiar apenas o par mais recente, não sei se adianta ou se faz diferença editá-la, até porque você já passou por todo o trabalho de me escrever a sua resposta, mas tenho muito interesse em saber a sua sugestão. Precisaria de outra pergunta?

Comment: Sua questão já sugere a ação envolvendo o arquivo par e sendo recentes, e quanto ao trabalho/tempo demandado, entenda que é resultado proveitoso de período de isolamento tratado como terapia ocupacional/recreativa.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Itens de **1.** a **5.**:

> *Já dei uma pesquisada e tenho uma noção básica mas gostaria de saber se alguém saberia esclarecer o que essa expressão faz e como ela faz.*

- Itens de **6.** a **9.**:

> *...copiar arquivos mais recentes de um diretório para outro. Mas além de ser o mais recente (data de criação) tenho outras condições pra cópia:*
>
> - *Começar com "Relatório Financeiro"*
> - *Arquivos com o mesmo nome em formatos diferentes, um em .PDF outro em .XLSX.*

- Itens **10.** e **11.** [mover apenas 1 par de arquivos (1 .pdf + 1 .xlsx) por execução]:

> *..mas gostaria de copiar apenas o par mais recente...*

---

**1.** A execução do comando **`Dir /B /A-D /O-D`** vai resultar na listagem de itens da pasta atual, onde essa saída vai retornar apenas os nomes de arquivos numa forma *"básica"*, um simples ***`nome-de-arquivo.extensão`*** e também não listando o `drive:\caminho\completo\para\nome-de-arquivo.extensão`

```batch-file
Dir            // lista arquvivos e pastas no Diretorio atual
Dir /B         // lista arquvivos e pastas na forma Básica, sem drive/caminho completo
Dir /A-D       // lista arquivos apenas, por excluir os itens com Atributo de Diretório,
               // observe que o "-" significa exclir o item, como em:

                  /A-D <==> -Diretórios <==> liste os itens, menos com Atributo -Diretórios
                  /A-A <==> -Arquivos   <==> liste os itens, menos com Atributo -Arquivos

               // observe que sem o "-" significa restringir/limitar ao item, como em:

                  /AD <==> Diretórios <==> liste os itens com Atributo Diretórios
                  /AA <==> Arquivos   <==> liste os itens com Atributo Arquivos

Dir /O-D       // lista arquivos em uma dada Ordem, nesse caso, por Data
               // observe que o "-" aqui vai significar uma inversão da ordenação padrão: 

                  /OD  <==> Ordenar por Data <==> liste do mais antigo para o mais recente/novo
                  /O-D <==> Ordenar por Data <==> liste do mais recente/novo para o mais antigo

Dir/B/A-D/O-D  // liste os nome de arquivos, exclindo os caminho/pastas, na ordem
               // inversa, por data de modificação/data de criação (o que for mais recente).
```

- Resulta:

```batch-file
> Dir /B /A-D /O-D
Q99999.txt
A99999.txt
Q99999.cmd
I99999.png
```

---

**2.** O redirecionamento feito pelo operador `"|"` da saída do comando **`dir`** é tratado no comando **`Findstr`**, e esse vai resultar numa listagem `N`umerada de todas as linhas resultantes da execução do comando anterior, **`dir`**.

```batch-file
Dir/B/A-D/O-D  // liste arquivos na ordem inversa de data de modificação/criação (mais recente).
^              // o escaping para o uso do pipe "|", que é necessário no for/f ('^|')
|              // redireciona a saída do comando anterior (Dir/B/A-D/O-D) para o Findstr
Findstr /N "^" // vai listar a saída obtida no comando anterior, Númerando todas as linhas.
```

- Resulta:

```batch-file
> Dir /B /A-D /O-D | Findstr /N "^"
1:Q99999.txt
2:A99999.txt
3:Q99999.cmd
4:I99999.png
```

---

**3.** O comando **`For /F`** loop vai criar um laço para manipular as ações resultantes dos comandos **`Dir/B..| Findstr..`**, capturando a saída para fazer o uso destas separando-as de forma pré-definida, para atender no seu delimitador (**`delims=:`**) definido, e os elementos da primeira ocorrências (**`tokens= [1]`** ), e todos (**`*`**) os elementos da segunda até última ocorrência (**`tokens=1-[*]`** ).

- Para todo e qualquer elemento/string que figurar antes do delimitador **"`:`"** (na primeira ocorrência do delimitador), será tratada na variável em loop **`%%A`**, e todas as ocorrências após a primeira ocorrência, ou seja, todas as ocorrências/strings após **`%%A`**, serão tratadas na variável em loop **`%%B`**

```batch-file
[ comando  em  loop]                  [ sáida  em  loop ]
Dir /B /A-D /O-D | Findstr /N "^"       1:Q99999.txt

<elemento %%A > [delimitador] <elemento(s) %%B>
      1               :          Q99999.txt
      2               :          A99999.txt
      3               :          Q99999.cmd
      4               :          I99999.png
```

**4.** Para explicar as ações desse código em lote/batch, vou retirar (explicando), o que não é necessário (ou dispensável):

```batch-file
@Echo off
Set "Xnewest=2" // define uma variavél atribuindo o numero 2 como valor
For /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
'Dir /B /A-D /O-D ^| Findstr /N "^"'
) Do If %%A Leq %Xnewest%    echo  Move "%%B" "X:\Path\to\dest\"
             // 2            ecoe  Move "%%B" "X:\Path\to\dest\"
             // 2 imprima na tela  Move "%%B" "X:\Path\to\dest\"
```

- Para cada item obtido das saídas resultantes da listagem do comando **`Dir..| Findstr`**, pegue **`%%A`**, que é o número que foi atribuído a linha atual da saída do comando **`Dir`** pelo **`Findstr`**, e se esse o número de linha é igual **`Equ`** ou menor **`Lss`** (**`Equ`  [ou]  `Lss`  <==>  `Leq`**), ecoe/imprima o comando **`Move..`**.

- O comando **`echo Move..`** vai apenas possibilitar uma verificação da saída do loop processado, para que o autor do código, ou o autor da pergunta, tenha a possibilidade de checar se os arquivos onde o comando efetivamente ocorre, satisfaz a condição no objetivo proposto, onde se observa que:

```batch-file
                [Dir] Liste arquivos dos mais recentes aos mais antigos e apenas nomes
            [Findstr] Enumere as linhas dessa saída, na forma, "numero" + ":" + "nome.extensão"
[For + if (%%A ≦ 2)] Se número da linha é menor ou igual a 2, mova item %%B para drive:\pasta\
```

**5.** Componentes que devem satisfazer/observar para tornar eficaz esse loop/bat:

- o bat está em execução na mesma pasta onde os arquivos estão sendo "manipulados" em loop
- o bat em execução, obrigatoriamente é mais antigo, ou tem a sua modificação/edição anterior aos arquivos em loop

**6.** Considerando a utilidade/aplicação do código comentado, e fazendo uma sugestão para limitar sua ação em apenas os dois arquivos **`.pdf`**, e **`.xlsx`** mais recentes, com o nome iniciando em "Relatório Financeiro":

```batch-file
@echo off && cd/d "z:\Pasta\de\Origem\" 

for %%i in (xlsx pdf)do for /F tokens^=1*delims^=: %%A in (
     'dir/b/a-d/o-d .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.%%~i"^|findstr/n .
     ')do if %%~A leq 2 echo=move /y ".\%%~B" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
```

- Mesmo código/resultado em versão com layout convencional:

```batch-file
@echo off 

cd /d "F:\Pasta\Origem"

for %%i in (xlsx,pdf) do ( 
     for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:-d .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.%%~i" ^| findstr /n .') do (
         if %%~A leq 2 echo=move /y ".\%%~B" "X:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
        )
    )
```

**7.** Na sugestão proposta no item **6.**, estou replicando o comando **`echo`** possibilitando a execução em testes/verificações, após isso, é só remover o `echo=` para efetiva movimentação dos arquivos.

```batch-file
@echo off && cd/d "z:\Pasta\de\Origem\" 

for %%i in (xlsx pdf)do for /F tokens^=1*^delims^=: %%A in (
     'dir/b/a-d/o-d .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.%%~i"^|findstr/n .
     ')do if %%~A leq 2 move /y ".\%%~B" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
```

- Mesmo código/resultado em versão com layout convencional:

```batch-file
@echo off 

cd /d "F:\Pasta\Origem"

for %%i in (xlsx,pdf) do ( 
     for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:-d .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.%%~i" ^| findstr /n .') do (
         if %%~A leq 2 move /y ".\%%~B" "X:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
        )
    )
```

**8.** Para mover arquivos com os mesmos nomes e diferentes extensões, aplicando a ordem por data de modificação/criação (o que for mais recente), aplicando aos arquivo `.pdf` e também `mesmos_nome.xlsx`:

```batch-file
@echo off && cd/d "z:\Pasta\de\Origem\" 

for /F tokens^=1*delims^=: %%A in ('dir/b/a-d/o-d/tc .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.xlsx"^|findstr/n .
   ')do if %%~A leq 2 for %%i in (.pdf,%%~xB)do move /y ".\%%~nB%%~i" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
```

- Mesmo código/resultado em versão com layout convencional:

```batch-file
@echo off

cd /d "z:\Pasta\de\Origem\" 

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:-d /t:c .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.xlsx" ^| findstr /n .') do (
     if %%~A leq 2 for %%i in (.pdf,%%~xB) do move /y ".\%%~nB%%~i" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
    )
```

**9.**  Para aplicar obter os resultados apenas em arquivos onde o listagem seja por ordem de data de criação (não modificação), apenas adicionar **`/TC`**

```batch-file
@echo off && cd/d "z:\Pasta\de\Origem\" 

for /F tokens^=1*delims^=: %%A in ('dir/b/a-d//o-d/tc .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.xlsx"^|findstr/n .
   ')do if %%~A leq 2 for %%i in (.pdf,%%~xB)do move /y ".\%%~nB%%~i" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
```

- Mesmo código/resultado em versão com layout convencional:

```batch-file
@echo off

cd /d "z:\Pasta\de\Origem\" 

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /b /a:-d /t:c .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.xlsx" ^| findstr /n .') do (
     if %%~A leq 2 for %%i in (.pdf,%%~xB) do move /y ".\%%~nB%%~i" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
    )
```

**10.** Para pegar o arquivo mais recente, quer seja este um `.pdf` ou um `.xlsx`, e usar o mesmo nome para (do arquivo mais recente) e movê-lo em "par", (.`xlsx + .pdf` ou `.pdf + .xlsx`) para outra pasta:

```batch-file
@echo off && cd /d "z:\Pasta\de\Origem\"

for /f tokens^=* %%i in (
    'dir/b/a-d/o-d/tc .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.*"^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe/eli "\.pdf \.xlsx"')do (
         move /y ".\%%~nxi" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\." && if /i "%%~xi" == ".xlsx" >nul (
             move /y ".\%%~ni.xlsx" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\." ) else >nul (
                 move /y ".\%%~ni.pdf" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\.")
                    ) & goto :eOf
```

```batch-file
Dir/B/A-D/O-D/TC  // liste arquivos na ordem inversa de data (criação)
^                 // o escaping para o uso do pipe "|", que é necessário no for/f ('^|')
|                 // redireciona a saída do comando anterior (Dir/B/A-D/O-D/T:C) para o Findstr
Findstr/ELI       // obtem no comando anterior, arquivos que terminam (End) Literalmente Insensitivo
"\.pdf \.xlsx"    // obtem as linhas que terminarem Literalmente com ".pdf" ou ".xlsx" caso 
                  // Lnsensitivo (independente de caixa alta ou baixa)
               
                  // observe que o "\." é diferente de ".", onde sem o uso do "escape" \, vai 
                  // significar para o Findstr "qualquer caratere", mas já o \. vai sinalizar
                  // Literalmente "." o ponto, assim resultando nas extensões "."+pdf e/ou ".xlsx"

if /i             // uso do if em condição de comparação de caso Iinsensitivo  
"%%~xi"==".xlsx"  // se a eXtensão ("%%~xi") do arquivo em loop for igual ".xlsx", ele move tambémm
                  // o arquivo com o mesmo Nome + eXtensão ".pdf" par a pasta de destino, caso o 
                  // contrario aconteça, o arquivo ".pdf" é o mais velho dentro do loop, vai 
                  // inverter a ação, movendo primeiro o .pdf, e depois o arquvo de mesmo nome .xlsx

Goto :eOf         // como a primeiro laço/loop já foi excutado, o par também já foi movido, e 
                  // entendendo que os outros arquivos do loop não são mais necessários, então 
                  // aborta-se a execução do loop/processamento, movendo a execução do batch 
                  // para o final do arquivo (Goto End Of File)
```

**11.** Caso em seus arquivos, os de extensão "`.pdf`" são sempre os mais recentes, e precisa apenas definir a ação para que se baseie nessa extensão para obter o nomde do arquivo "par" em "`xlsx`", ou o contrário, invertendo ".pdf"/".xlsx", a sugestão seira:

```batch-file
@echo off

cd/d "z:\Pasta\de\Origem\"

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('
    dir/b/a-d/o-d/tc .\"Relat?rio Financeiro*.pdf"')do >nul (
     move /y ".\%%~ni.xlsx" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
     move /y ".\%%~nxi" "x:\Pasta\de\Destino\."
     goto :eOf
    )
```

---

Explicações adicionais sobre **`for /f`**, **`skip`**, **`tokens`** e **`delims`**:

- ***[Alguém poderia explicar este código em batch para mim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466209/131559)***

Algumas referências para consulta/apoio in `/English`:

- **[IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
- **[Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**
- **[Move](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)**
- **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[Echo on | off](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**
- **[Redirections in bat file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Tive apenas uma dificuldade em fazê-lo funcionar por data de criação. Por algum motivo funciona com data de modificação e não com data de criação. Usando a estrutura convencional eu mudei apenas ```dir /b /a:-d /o:-d``` por ```dir /b /a:-d /t:-c``` e deixou de funcionar.

Comment: @sena Não tem opção de uso "inverso" com **`-`** em **`-C `** para a flag **`/T`**,  apenas adicione o **`TC`**: **`Dir /B/A-D/O-D/TC`**

Comment: Nossa cara, esse código ficou demais, parabéns!

Comment: Só por curiosidade, existe alguma limitação com relação a usar caminhos que sejam de pastas compartilhadas? Testando local ele foi perfeito. Quando alterei o destino e a fonte de onde seriam copiados os arquivos para endereços de diretórios no servidor, ele não completa a transferência. Desde já, muitíssimo obrigado pelo seu tempo, eu aprendi muito!

Comment: @Sena seria o caso de substituir o move por copy, ou por robocopy, ou ainda pode tenta atribuir uma unidade (`subst` ou `net use ...`) para o local remoto, depois altere para copiar para essa unidade "virtual" apontada para a pasta remota. Obrigado a voce tbm por ler, testar, etc...

Comment: Substitui por `copy` para fazer um [teste](https://paiza.io/projects/gcQcHWmZ1TztsVchaFNlSw?language=bash). Experimentei também `net use x: "\\servidor\"` mas não foi. Nos próximos dias vou mexer mais nesse código, não tenho certeza se a minha sintaxe está correta.

Comment: @sena seria mais fácil usar o copy e depois apagar os arquivos na origem.

Comment: @sena eu n tenho como testar,  mas use \\+\\caminho; `move /y ".\%%~ni.pdf" \\\\remoto\`

Comment: @sena veja essa **[resposta](https://superuser.com/a/282974)** e a sugestão acima.

Comment: obrigado, vou experimentá-las!